# "The Unfinished ________ Waltz"

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, music

<sup>This puzzle can be solved as puzzle on its own, but its solution is also part of Deusovi's [Community Metapuzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45927/community-metapuzzle-the-broken-time-machine).</sup>

---

[image: The Unfinished ________ Waltz]

Above is the sheet music for the universally acclaimed *"The Unfinished ________ Waltz"*, by renowned composer, Alconja <sup><sub>(1763 – 1844)</sub></sup>. A deeply moving piece, to be sure, though sadly it remains incomplete...

...*However*, it has long been speculated, given Alconja's strange, non-standard notation, that there may be more information hidden within the composition than is superficially apparent. Of course, to be fair, some scholars downplay this, arguing that the red is simply emotive emphasis on Alconja's part, pointing to the bleak juxtaposition of haunting silence and the aggressiveness of the blood-red lines enraging the final passages in particular. That being said, the lyrics *do* seem to back up the former theory (even as they pull at the heart strings).

Perhaps an astute connoisseur of fine music, such as yourself, may actually be able to piece together the clues and lay the centuries of conjecture to rest. So, the question is: Can you finish the unfinished? Or more specifically, ***what is the missing word from the title of the song?***

---

<sup>**Note 1:** All descriptive text is just flavour. The sheet music and lyrics are all you need.</sup>

<sup>**Note 2:** Very little, if any, actual musical knowledge is required for this puzzle. In fact, you can mostly think of the sheet music above in purely visual terms, with a fair bit of the notation being superfluous. However, here's the absolute basics of music theory, which may help in understanding things a little better:</sup>

- <sup>This particular song is played in "3/4" time, which basically just means that there are three beats per "bar" (a group of notes, separated by the vertical lines)</sup>
- <sup>Each horizontal line, and each gap between those lines, represents a uniquely pitched note</sup>
- <sup>Notes are given lettered names from A to G, which repeat cyclically, though a given note is still different from it's similarly named sibling 7 notes higher/lower</sup>
- <sup>The bottom line is E, the bottom gap is F, and so on, continuing up with G, A, B, C, D, E, making the top line another, different, F</sup>
- <sup>A "rest" (represented by the squiggly lines) is effectively a silent pause for a single beat</sup>

---

**Hints and Clarifications**

1. The two shades of red are *only* used to make it easier to tell exactly what is highlighted and to prevent neighbouring highlights from visually bleeding into each other. The important thing is *if* a line or gap is highlighted, *not* the shade of red (i.e. for the first bar, E3 and C4 are highlighted and the other notes are not, with no need to distinguish further).
2. > Solving this puzzle involves a couple of steps, and for the initial step(s), you can safely ignore the highlighting and concentrate on the song structure and the lyrics.

Comment: The music doesn't sound so relatively bad at all. Very moving indeed.

Comment: So I dont know nothing, absolutely nothing(eg I dont understand anything of Note 2), about music except listening it - can I solve it ?

Comment: As a matter of naming convention, the stave goes from bottom to top E3, F3, G3, A3, B3, C4, D4, E4, F4 in case people don't want to overuse top and bottom.

Comment: @ArbitraryKangaroo - All you need to know is the stuff in note 2. Anything in particular you don't understand? I tried to keep it rudimentary, but I'll try to rephrase in even simpler terms: 1) Notes in this song are in groups of three. 2) Each horizontal line and horizontal gap represents a unique sounding note. 3) & 4) Notes are named as per boboquacks comment above (from bottom to top, alternating line, gap, line, gap, etc). 5) The squiggly lines ("rests") are used in place of notes when there's a beat of silence (i.e. a lack of a note).

Comment: So, for example, if it helps you could think of the line as: `C4 G3 - | D4 A4 F3 | - - - | F4 - -` (without the highlighted parts notated obviously)

Comment: In case anyone's curious, [this](http://vocaroo.com/i/s1rQEW3q3YXB) is what it sounds like. (And [here](http://vocaroo.com/i/s1Bb7s51oGvR)'s a version without the "drums" in the background.)

Comment: @Deusovi - My god. It's so beautiful. I feel as though my soul has been torn from my body.

Comment: Are there just two shades of red here?

Comment: @JonathanAllan - that's right (nothing sneakily hidden, you could solve it from a print out)

Comment: Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llelj.png)?

Comment: @JonathanAllan - looks good. Though now that you've gone to the effort of recolouring (apologies if I created colour blindness frustrations), I feel like I should clarify and say that the difference doesn't actually matter. I could've highlighted things with a single colour, I just used two so it was clearer and didn't all bleed together...

Comment: So we don't need to know about the accents (they aren't in note 2)?

Comment: @boboquack - Correct. Apart from the lyrics, only note values, rests and highlights (all grouped by bar) matter. The rest is irrelevant.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If we continue from [MMAdams' discovery](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/45914/5208) (if you like anything in this answer, go upvote MMAdams'!) and

> highlight cells in the Sudoku grid corresponding to notes falling on shaded lines/spaces in the music,

we get the following pattern:

> `C G e D A f B F E   #   #   #
>  A F E C B e D G f   #   #         #
>  D B f G F E e C A   #   #   #   #   #
>  e C D B E A F f G     #     #     #
>  E A B F f G C D e   -----------------
>  F f G e D C A E B     #     #
>  B E C A G D f e F     #         # #
>  f e F E C B G A D     #     #   #   #
>  G D A f e F E B C     #     #   #   #`

where e.g.

> in the first bar the shaded notes on the staff are `C` and `e`; the notes are `C G e`; so the first and third of those cells get marked. Another equivalent way to say this: for each note, transfer the shading (if any) on that note's line/space to the corresponding space in the Sudoku grid.

This, if you squint at it a bit, says

> Violin

which also (note: the following contains a slightly spoilery conjecture about the metapuzzle)

> has the necessary three syllables, not to mention lots of Roman numerals like the other things found so far that feed into the the metapuzzle.

Comment: Remark: If this is correct, I hope Alconja wlil give the +100 bounty to MMAdams rather than to me.

Comment: Can you give a little more detail on how the shading corresponds to your grid?  I'm failing to see a relationship.

Comment: oh, sorry, yes, I should have been more explicit. Hang on a second and I'll edit.

Comment: Does it make better sense now?

Comment: Okay, so most of the shading serves no purpose?  Only the shading that matches notes is relevant?

Comment: Yup, that's right.

Comment: That seems... un-Alconjian.

Comment: Well, maybe I've got it all wrong and Alconja will be along shortly to explain. But it seems pretty convincing to me.

Comment: The `D` in the second bar isn't actually on a shaded line, so it should actually spell "Violin" without that extra thing between the 'V' and the 'i'. It does seem to fit with the music theme of the puzzle as well, but I also would have thought the other shaded lines were significant somehow.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain - The solution is the intersection of the highlights and the notes. If I *only* highlighted the "correct" locations, the sudoku=note portion would've been unnecessary, since the highlights alone would've been sufficient. Every highlight is "used" (just extending left/right beyond their associated note to make it less obvious which note is highlighted) except for in the last line, where I added a bunch of unnecessary highlights for red herring+visual/thematic interest's sake. Perhaps makes the puzzle less than ideal, but that was my thought process in case you were curious...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan - Well done! This is correct. Though, with your blessings I'll award the bounty to MMAdams, since he solved the larger part of the overall solution (with you getting the tick).

Comment: @Alconja Ok, that makes more sense. I didn't think about it long enough to realize that without the extraneous data, solvers could skip a step.

Comment: The fact that MMAdams solved the larger -- and I think much harder -- part is exactly why they should get the +100. My thoughts about the puzzle before seeing that answer were along *entirely* the wrong lines.

Answer (score 30):

Edit:
I figured out the title I think!!!!

> The Unfinished Sudoku Waltz

"Boxes of boxes"

> Refers to the 9 boxes of 9 characters in a sudoku grid. There are 72 notes, 9 less than a Sudoku grid, plus, given the five lines of the staff and the four spaces between, we have nine notes total, e f A B C D E F G. (I used lowercase letters for the lower notes, for simplicity).

If you take all the notes given:

> And put an empty line in the middle 'Between these two lines, hidden, silence must fall' means you put empty spaces there like you do anywhere else there is a rest. Then you get a sudoku grid that looks like this:  (Edit: I fixed it! I had a G in the wrong place, oops, now it is solvable!)
>
> ```
> C G _ D A f _ _ _
> _ F _ C _ e D _ f
> _ B _ G _ _ e C _
> e C D B E _ _ _ G
> _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
> _ _ G e _ _ _ E B
> B E _ _ G _ _ _ F
> _ e F E _ _ _ _ _
> _ _ _ _ _ _ E _ _
> ```

Which solves to this:

> ```
> C G e D A f B F E
> A F E C B e D G f
> D B f G F E e C A
> e C D B E A F f G
> E A B F f G C D e
> F f G e D C A E B
> B E C A G D f e F
> f e F E C B G A D
> G D A f e F E B C
> ```

I know my answer still isn't making use of the red markings, so I'm not sure this is right, but it was fun to do!
EDIT: Gareth McCaughan figured out the title was

> Violin

by combining the marked notes with the sudoku grid (Thanks Gareth! And anyone else, go upvote his answer), so this question is long since solved, but I figured I'd make a musical version of the whole answer anyway, so here is what it looks like:

> [image]

[and here is what it sounds like](http://vocaroo.com/i/s0tyk5zpa9WL) (You will have to imagine the lyrics on your own since I do not think my roommate would appreciate me singing riddles in the middle of the night.)

Alconja, this was a super fun puzzle!

Comment: I don't think it's clear that we need to fill in the rests. Another possibility is that the rests are just to be ignored. (I don't think there need be a close correspondence between individual notes and the words/syllables beneath them.)

Comment: I *can* confirm that it's not "Sudoku". Still, I think you're on the right track!

Comment: (My comment above is addressed to an older version of the answer.) It surely can't possibly be coincidence that this works out so neatly. I wonder what's up with the red markings.

Comment: Awesome work! But you're not done yet. :) It's at this point the red highlights become important...

Comment: Wonder what it sounds like now… anyone?

Comment: I've given Gareth the tick, obviously, since he got the final answer. But I'm giving you the (well deserved) bounty, since you solved the larger/harder part of the puzzle.

Comment: Just noticed your edit. That's great. :) (@boboquack - you may be interested also)

Comment: The sound-link is (no longer) working. Would be great if we could link to something with a bit more permance for the future...

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer: I know the final answer, and that's it. Alconja stated that that would not confer any advantage.)

### <s>Partial Answer</s> Wild Guesses

There are exactly 32 notes in the piece. The lyrics say "square things away, there'll be no rest at all". 32 is not a square number, but it is suspiciously close to one. This may clue that we have to arrange the notes in a square.

Denoting high C, D, E, and F with capital letters and the rest lowercase, here's what one potential pattern looks like:

```
CgDafF
CeDfbg
eC  eC
Db  Eg
geEbbE
gFeFEE
```

This seems to satisfy "boxes of boxes", but "these two lines" doesn't seem to be satisfied here.

---

```
CgDa
fFCe
Dfbg
eCeC
????
DbEg
geEb
bEgF
eFEE
```

is another option. This makes two squares, and if four notes are added there, then we have 36 notes.  Alternatively, `????` and `DbEg` can switch places: this places the missing notes at "there'll be no rest at all, be**tween these** two lines, hidden, silence must fall". This fits better with the lyrics at that point, but not "square away".

Comment: @all - Just to back up deusovi's disclaimer, I can confirm that knowing the final answer will not help him in the slightest.

Comment: I suppose 32 could be the 5-D generalised cube (hyper-hypercube?)... if Alconja's being poetic